# Testing rails-models using Mintest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rails-models

How to test after_create methods in rails model using rails Minitest? Is using `respond_to?` correct? Can anyone please suggest the best method for testing the after_create methods like sending mail and so?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mocha` gem, you can do `expects` that method to be invoked like

### user_test.rb

```
test 'callbacks on create' do
  user = new_user
  user.expects(:send_email)
  user.save
end

private
def new_user
  User.new(email: 'some_email', first_name: 'first_name', last_name: 'last_name')
end
```

### user.rb

```
after_commit :send_email, on: :create

private
def send_email
  // Your email code or some business logic here
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer! But isn't there any way to do the same with rails default Minitest?

Comment: I'm not sure, but adding `mocha gem` to your test env will give you a lot of helpers needed in testing. Please give it a try.